# name 'self' is not defined and how to ask for it outside of __init__

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, class, self

There are questions about self but I can't find anywhere a good and easy to understand explanation why I can't do this and how I should do this correctly. Way how this is handled is very counterintuitive to me and many other people that start working with python. Example:

```
class cls:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = True

    if self.a:
        print("self.a is True")
    else:
        print("self.a if False")
```

I have no idea how I can access or check "a" outside of init in a class. If I'll do something like this:

```
class cls:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = True

    if a:
        print("a is True")
    else:
        print("a if False")
```

Then I get NameError. At some point  I always get to this problem and I can't understand how to handle this correctly. Should I do this outside of class with function? Whatever you try that should make sense doesn't work in this case. Another example:

```
class cls:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = True

    if cls.a:
        print("self.a is True")
    else:
        print("self.a if False")
```

Gives IndentationError: unexpected indent.

Comment: Is the indentation you see on the site (especially lines 5-8) the same as you have in the editor?

Comment: The `if` statement you have belongs in another function! You can't have it hanging outside of a method because you've put it inside a class.

Comment: Outside the methods you're just inside the class definition - there can't possibly be an instance `self` when you haven't finished defining the class to instantiate! What are you actually expecting to happen here?

Comment: When do you want this if statement to be executed?

Comment: "There are questions about self but I can't find anywhere a good and easy to understand explanation why I can't do this and how I should do this correctly." - **what is "this"**? **When** do you want the `if` block to run, and **which object** should be used?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you just need to wrap your code in a function like:

```
class myClass():
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = True

    def check_a(self):
        if self.a:
            print('a is True')
        else:
            print('a is not True')
```

And use that like:

```
inst = myClass()
inst.check_a()
```

which will do what you'd expect, print: 'a is True'

Hope that could clear things up a bit.